# Earth Engine: how to access the dates from a list retrieved from an image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, image, datetime, feature-collection

I have implemented the answer of Noel Gorelick to the question:
[Earth Engine get dates from imageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307115/earth-engine-get-dates-from-imagecollection)
It is the following code:

```
var dates = s1_collection_f
    .map(function(image) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
    })
    .distinct('date')
    .aggregate_array('date')
```

It successfully returned a list of dates in the format 'YYYY-MM-dd', but I cannot read that list. I need to get every single date to be joined in the layers names. It seems to be weird, but I can't loop through the elements of the list. I have tried the following:

1. The console returns  for each element of the list:

   for (var index in dates) {
   print(dates[index]);
   }
2. Nothing is returned:

   for (var i=0; i< dates.length(); i++) {
   print(dates[i]);
   }

How can I loop through the list and get each date?

Comment: The use of for-loops is discouraged in Earth Engine. You should use map method with dates list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is an example for joining layers names to every single date, in an arbitrarily selected ('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD') Image Collection, by using **map** instead a for loop.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-104.18, 40.47); 

//Load S1 ImageCollection and filter by Location and Date
var s1_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01')
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(pt));

var s1_collection_lst = s1_collection.toList(s1_collection.size());

var names = s1_collection_lst.map(function (img)  {
  
  return ee.Image(img).id().slice(0, 17);
  
});

print(names);

var dates = s1_collection.aggregate_array("system:time_start");

dates = dates.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Date(ele).format().slice(0,10);
  
});

var paired = names.zip(dates);

var join_name_date = paired.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.String(ee.List(ele).get(0)).cat(ee.List(ele).get(1));
  
});

print(join_name_date);
```

Script can be ran in following [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ecb564ca344271aa75a3ada07a89ff4).